# Flutter throws an error while fetching data. How can I fix it?

Tags: dart, flutter

I was trying to export google sheet data to JSON and displaying the table in a flutter app with the help of an example explained in an Medium [article](https://medium.com/@gerard.horgan1/getting-data-from-googlesheets-and-displaying-it-elegantly-using-the-paginateddatatable-class-in-cb54f4e41b28), but it throws an error.

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(717)] Isolate (407760049) 'main.dart:_spawn()' exited with an error
E/flutter (13106): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (13106): type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
E/flutter (13106): #0      new Result.fromJson (package:supershopping_flutter_app/main.dart:39:28)
E/flutter (13106): #1      parseResults.<anonymous closure> (package:supershopping_flutter_app/main.dart:19:46)
E/flutter (13106): #2      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:414:29)
E/flutter (13106): #3      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:219:19)
E/flutter (13106): #4      parseResults (package:supershopping_flutter_app/main.dart:19:62)
E/flutter (13106): #5      _IsolateConfiguration.apply (package:flutter/src/foundation/isolates.dart:88:16)
E/flutter (13106): #6      _spawn.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/isolates.dart:96:30)
E/flutter (13106): #7      Timeline.timeSync (dart:developer/timeline.dart:168:22)
E/flutter (13106): #8      _spawn (package:flutter/src/foundation/isolates.dart:93:12)
E/flutter (13106): #9      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:292:17)
E/flutter (13106): #10     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
I/flutter (13106): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (13106): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:
I/flutter (13106): The getter 'length' was called on null.
I/flutter (13106): Receiver: null
I/flutter (13106): Tried calling: length
```

data.json

```
[
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    },
    {
        "sex": "Both sexes",
        "region": "State",
        "year": 2016,
        "statistic": "Population 2011 (Number)",
        "value": 4588252
    }
]
```

main.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Result>> fetchResults(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client.get('https://imtusharrai.github.io/app-data/data.json');

  // Use the compute function to run parseResults in a separate isolate
  return compute(parseResults, response.body);
}

// A function that will convert a response body into a List<Result>
List<Result> parseResults(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Result>((json) => Result.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class Result {
  final String sex;
  final String region;
  final int year;
  final String statistic;
  final String value;

  Result({this.sex, this.region, this.year, this.statistic, this.value});

  bool selected = false;

  factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Result(
      sex: json['sex'] as String,
      region: json['region'] as String,
      year: json['year'] as int,
      statistic: json['statistic'] as String,
      value: json['value'] as String,
    );
  }
}

class ResultsDataSource extends DataTableSource {
  final List<Result> _results;
  ResultsDataSource(this._results);

  void _sort<T>(Comparable<T> getField(Result d), bool ascending) {
    _results.sort((Result a, Result b) {
      if (!ascending) {
        final Result c = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
      }
      final Comparable<T> aValue = getField(a);
      final Comparable<T> bValue = getField(b);
      return Comparable.compare(aValue, bValue);
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int _selectedCount = 0;

  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    assert(index >= 0);
    if (index >= _results.length) return null;
    final Result result = _results[index];
    return DataRow.byIndex(
        index: index,
        selected: result.selected,
        onSelectChanged: (bool value) {
          if (result.selected != value) {
            _selectedCount += value ? 1 : -1;
            assert(_selectedCount >= 0);
            result.selected = value;
            notifyListeners();
          }
        },
        cells: <DataCell>[
          DataCell(Text('${result.sex}')),
          DataCell(Text('${result.region}')),
          DataCell(Text('${result.year}')),
          DataCell(Text('${result.statistic}')),
          DataCell(Text('${result.value}')),
        ]);
  }

  @override
  int get rowCount => _results.length;

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => _selectedCount;

  void _selectAll(bool checked) {
    for (Result result in _results) result.selected = checked;
    _selectedCount = checked ? _results.length : 0;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class DataTableDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  ResultsDataSource _resultsDataSource = ResultsDataSource([]);
  bool isLoaded = false;

  @override
  _DataTableDemoState createState() => _DataTableDemoState();
}

class _DataTableDemoState extends State<DataTableDemo> {
  ResultsDataSource _resultsDataSource = ResultsDataSource([]);
  bool isLoaded = false;
  int _rowsPerPage = PaginatedDataTable.defaultRowsPerPage;
  int _sortColumnIndex;
  bool _sortAscending = true;

  void _sort<T>(
      Comparable<T> getField(Result d), int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
    _resultsDataSource._sort<T>(getField, ascending);
    setState(() {
      _sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
      _sortAscending = ascending;
    });
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
    final results = await fetchResults(http.Client());
    if (!isLoaded) {
      setState(() {
        _resultsDataSource = ResultsDataSource(results);
        isLoaded = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData();
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Data tables'),
        ),
        body: ListView(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0), children: <Widget>[
          PaginatedDataTable(
              header: const Text('Census Data'),
              rowsPerPage: _rowsPerPage,
              onRowsPerPageChanged: (int value) {
                setState(() {
                  _rowsPerPage = value;
                });
              },
              sortColumnIndex: _sortColumnIndex,
              sortAscending: _sortAscending,
              onSelectAll: _resultsDataSource._selectAll,
              columns: <DataColumn>[
                DataColumn(
                    label: const Text('Sex'),
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>(
                            (Result d) => d.sex, columnIndex, ascending)),
                DataColumn(
                    label: const Text('Region'),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>(
                            (Result d) => d.region, columnIndex, ascending)),
                DataColumn(
                    label: const Text('Year'),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>(
                            (Result d) => d.year, columnIndex, ascending)),
                DataColumn(
                    label: const Text('Data'),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>(
                            (Result d) => d.statistic, columnIndex, ascending)),
                DataColumn(
                    label: const Text('Value'),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>(
                            (Result d) => d.value, columnIndex, ascending)),
              ],
              source: _resultsDataSource)
        ]));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: DataTableDemo()));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Your problem in this line  `value: json['value'] as String` which doesn't make sense because the value DataType is int

it should be like this

```
value: json['value']
```